# Lilypond \easyHeadsOn: How to show german note name H

Tags: lilypond

In german the english note name `B` is named `H` (while english `Bb` is named `B`)

The german note name `H` can be entered when using `\language "deutsch"`. But when using `\easyHeadsOn` the

```
\language "deutsch"
{ \easyHeadsOn h2 }
```

I'd expect the letter `H` to be shown in the head. But instead the english letter `B` is shown.

`\set printNotesLanguage = "deutsch"` seems to have no effect.

```
\language "deutsch"
melody = {
  \easyHeadsOn h'2
}

<<
  \new Staff { \key c \major \melody }
  \new NoteNames { \set printNotesLanguage = "deutsch" \melody }
>>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\easyHeadsOn` uses the `NoteHead.note-names` property for the displayed names. If not specified it directly translates the pitch class using ASCII rather than using the localized `note-names->string`. So you may do

```
\language "deutsch"
melody = {
  \override NoteHead.note-names = ##("c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "a" "h")
  \easyHeadsOn h'2
}

<<
  \new Staff { \key c \major \melody }
  \new NoteNames { \set printNotesLanguage = "deutsch" \melody }
>>
```

or alternatively make the whole thing localized:

```
#(define-public (note-head::brew-ez-stencil grob)
  (let* ((log (ly:grob-property grob 'duration-log))
         (pitch (ly:event-property (event-cause grob) 'pitch))
         (pitch-index (ly:pitch-notename pitch))
         (note-names (ly:grob-property grob 'note-names))
         (pitch-string (if (and (vector? note-names)
                                (> (vector-length note-names) pitch-index))
                           (vector-ref note-names pitch-index)
                           ((@@ (lily) note-name->string) pitch)))
         (staff-space (ly:staff-symbol-staff-space grob))
         (line-thickness (ly:staff-symbol-line-thickness grob))
         (stem (ly:grob-object grob 'stem #f))
         (stem-thickness (* (if stem
                                (ly:grob-property stem 'thickness)
                                1.3)
                            line-thickness))
         (font-size (ly:grob-property grob 'font-size 0))
         (radius (* (magstep font-size) (/ (+ staff-space line-thickness) 2)))
         (letter (make-fontsize-markup
                  -8
                  (make-center-align-markup (make-vcenter-markup pitch-string))))
         (filled-circle (make-draw-circle-markup radius 0 #t)))

    (ly:stencil-translate-axis
     (grob-interpret-markup
      grob
      (if (>= log 2)
          (make-combine-markup
           filled-circle
           (make-with-color-markup white letter))
          (make-combine-markup
           (make-combine-markup
            filled-circle
            (make-with-color-markup white (make-draw-circle-markup
                                           (- radius stem-thickness) 0 #t)))
           letter)))
     radius X)))

easyHeadsOn = {
  \override NoteHead.stencil = #note-head::brew-ez-stencil
  \override NoteHead.font-family = #'sans
  \override NoteHead.font-series = #'bold
}


\language "italiano"
melody = {
  \easyHeadsOn si'2
}

<<
  \new Staff { \key do \major \melody }
  \new NoteNames { \melody }
>>
```

EDIT: A version that allows differentiation between h and b:

```
#(define (note-head::brew-ez-stencil grob)
   (let* ((log (ly:grob-property grob 'duration-log))
          (pitch-string (ly:grob-property grob 'text))
          (staff-space (ly:staff-symbol-staff-space grob))
          (line-thickness (ly:staff-symbol-line-thickness grob))
          (stem (ly:grob-object grob 'stem #f))
          (stem-thickness (* (if stem
                                 (ly:grob-property stem 'thickness)
                                 1.3)
                             line-thickness))
          (font-size (ly:grob-property grob 'font-size 0))
          (radius (* (magstep font-size) (/ (+ staff-space line-thickness) 2)))
          (letter (make-fontsize-markup
                   -8
                   (make-center-align-markup (make-vcenter-markup pitch-string))))
          (filled-circle (make-draw-circle-markup radius 0 #t)))

     (ly:stencil-translate-axis
      (grob-interpret-markup
       grob
       (if (>= log 2)
           (make-combine-markup
            filled-circle
            (make-with-color-markup white letter))
           (make-combine-markup
            (make-combine-markup
             filled-circle
             (make-with-color-markup white (make-draw-circle-markup
                                            (- radius stem-thickness) 0 #t)))
            letter)))
      radius X)))

#(define (note-head::brew-ez-text grob)
   (let* ((pitch (ly:event-property (event-cause grob) 'pitch))
          (pitch-index (ly:pitch-notename pitch))
          (note-names (ly:grob-property grob 'note-names))
          (pitch-string (if (and (vector? note-names)
                                 (> (vector-length note-names) pitch-index))
                            (vector-ref note-names pitch-index)
                            (string
                             (integer->char
                              (+ (modulo (+ pitch-index 2) 7)
                                 (char->integer #\A)))))))
      pitch-string))

#(define (note-head::brew-ez-text-loc grob)
   (let* ((pitch (ly:event-property (event-cause grob) 'pitch))
         (pitch-index (ly:pitch-notename pitch))
         (note-names (ly:grob-property grob 'note-names))
         (pitch-string (if (and (vector? note-names)
                                (> (vector-length note-names) pitch-index))
                           (vector-ref note-names pitch-index)
                           ((@@ (lily) note-name->string) pitch))))
     pitch-string))

#(define ((note-name->german-string B-instead-of-Bb)
          pitch lowercase?)
   (let* ((name (ly:pitch-notename pitch))
          (alt-semitones ((@@ (lily) pitch-alteration-semitones) pitch))
          (n-a (if (member (cons name alt-semitones) `((6 . -1) (6 . -2)))
                   (cons 7 (+ (if B-instead-of-Bb 1 0) alt-semitones))
                   (cons name alt-semitones))))
     ((@@ (lily) conditional-string-capitalize)
      (vector-ref #("c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "a" "h" "b") (car n-a))
      lowercase?)))

#(define (note-head::brew-ez-text-german grob)
   (let* ((pitch (ly:event-property (event-cause grob) 'pitch))
          (pitch-index (ly:pitch-notename pitch))
          (note-names (ly:grob-property grob 'note-names))
          (pitch-string (if (and (vector? note-names)
                                 (> (vector-length note-names) pitch-index))
                            (vector-ref note-names pitch-index)
                            ((note-name->german-string #t) pitch #t))))
      pitch-string))

easyHeadsOn = {
  \override NoteHead.stencil = #note-head::brew-ez-stencil
  \override NoteHead.text = #note-head::brew-ez-text
  \override NoteHead.font-family = #'sans
  \override NoteHead.font-series = #'bold
}


\language "deutsch"
melody = {
  \easyHeadsOn
  h'2 b'
  \override NoteHead.text = #note-head::brew-ez-text-loc
  h'2 b'
  \override NoteHead.text = #note-head::brew-ez-text-german
  h'2 b'
}

<<
  \new Staff { \key c \major \melody }
  \new NoteNames { \melody }
>>
```

(this version makes the text come from the `NoteHead.text` property).

Comment: The first method shows h-flat where it should have b.

Comment: With the Lisp method get an error: `filename.ly:12:16: Wrong number of arguments to #<primitive-procedure ly:grob-object>`

Comment: @ElementsinSpace: That is true `h-flat` should show `b`. And this is also wrong outside `easyHeadsOn` e.g. in `NoteNames`.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace easy noteheads do not print accidentals. If you want it to do so you need to adapt `note-head::brew-ez-stencil`, which can be easily done.

Comment: @wolfrevo What Lilypond version are you on? I suppose this is due to the optional default to `ly:grob-object`, which has been added mid 2021, which should have been around 2.23.3. Of course you can always adapt the function from your local version.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Added a version for `b`.

Comment: @Lazy: Yes. It must at least a newer version. Tested with 2.24.1.

Comment: @Lazy: Your code solves the problem for noteheads. The notenames though are all printed as `h`. Is there a generic way to override the notenames used by `\new Notenames` that apply for `NoteHead` too?

Comment: @wolfrevo For the notenames you could do `\set noteNameFunction = #(lambda (pitch ctx) (note-name->german-markup pitch #t))`